# Python cx_Oracle Update

Tags: python, sql-update, cx-oracle

In my Python code when I ask the user to input a string to SELECT, it works but when I try the UPDATE using the same input doesn't allow me to execute

Here is my code after the connection has been successfully done

```
curs = connection.cursor()
str_input1 = str(input("Input : "))
str_input2 = str(input("Input : "))
statement = "UPDATE table SET variable1 = "+str_input1+" WHERE name = "+str_input2
curs.execute(statement)
connection.commit
```

In theory this following code should work and update the variable, but instead I get the error at line curs.execute(statement) saying

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: John: invalid identifier
```

John was the str_input2 for where clause

Maybe its the format that was giving me an error but I'm not too sure.

Can someone point out what was the problem with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because you're not quoting the values. You'd get the exact same error from a `SELECT` statement.

These statements search for rows where the `name` column matches the string `John`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "John"
UPDATE table SET variable1 = "Hi" WHERE name = "John"
```

These statements search for rows where the `name` columns matches the `John` column—and if there is no `John` column, that's an error:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = John
UPDATE table SET variable1 = "Hi" WHERE name = John
```

So, you *could* fix this by just putting quotes around the values.

But you really, really, really shouldn't. This opens you up to [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/), and stupid bugs where you don't quote or escape special characters properly, and performance problems where the database engine can't tell that you're running the same query over and over, and so on.

What you want to do is to use [SQL parameters](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15), instead of trying to format the string. I don't remember which parameter style cx_Oracle uses, but you can just `import cx_Oracle; print(cx_Oracle.paramstyle)`, and look it up [in the table](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) to find out. And then do something like:

```
statement = "UPDATE table SET variable1 = :v WHERE name = :n"
curs.execute(statement, {'v': str_input1, 'n': str_input2})
```

---

Also, a few side notes:

- `connection.commit` doesn't do anything; you're just referencing the `commit` method, not calling it. You need parentheses: `connection.commit()`
- `str(input())` is pointless. The `input` function always returns a string, so there's no reason to call `str` on it. (Unless you're using Python 2.x, in which case you should be using `raw_input()`, which returns a string, instead of using `input` to `eval` the string—opening up the same kinds of security problems as the SQL injection attack above—only to convert it back to a string.)